# How to find column with all same repeating character

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a `char(15) NOT NULL` column. I need to see if it is empty or contains all zeros. I can obviously do`= '000000000000000'` But is there a  way using `LIKE` so its not hard coded to 15? I don't see why the `[^0]` below doesn't match all zeros.

```
CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(IL.ItemNumber)) = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsEmpty
CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(IL.ItemNumber)) <> '' AND LTRIM(RTRIM(IL.ItemNumber)) NOT LIKE '[^0]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsZeros
```

I'm basically trying to validate the column. Trimming works for empty, but maybe there is a much cleaner/flexible way to accomplish both of these validations? Thanks!

Comment: `[^0]` matches only a single character, and this is because of the definition of the patterns used with `LIKE`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually there is [`REPLICATE()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function:

```
WHERE <column> = REPLICATE('0',15)
```

Funny thing, it's actually using 17 characters, exactly the same as the `'000000000000000'` literal.

<sup>(Reading again the question, I suppose you don't want the above either because it has the `15` hard coded.)</sup>

---

The `LIKE` condition you have is not working as expected because the `LIKE '[^0]'` would be true only if the column had exactly 1 character. I think you need to check if it has only 0s or not:

```
WHERE <column> NOT LIKE '%[^0]%'
```

To check if it has only 0s or only spaces, this do (for `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` columns) and you don't even have to trim the column:

```
WHERE <column> = '' 
   OR <column> NOT LIKE '%[^0]%'
```

Comment: Right, maybe I should of expanded in my question. This is raw data. So before this process, I'm padding/zero-filling (using `replicate`) the value if it is not empty.

Comment: Nice, that seems to work. I wish there was an elegant way to check for all zero and empty in the same `LIKE` clause, but reading through the msdn it doesn't look possible. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nevermind, I think `%[^0 ]%` will work for empty as well. Seriously, thanks!

Comment: Yes, but it will also allow strings like `'00 000  00 '`

Comment: Good point. For my scenario, that is acceptable.

Comment: Use the @ypercubes answer above for performance but I thought I'd throw this out there: `WHERE len(replace(<column>, '0','') = 0`

Comment: Also, it was never mentioned why the `NOT LIKE '%[^0]%'` was sufficient to exclude the null values as well.  It's a byproduct of a NOT expression which will always exclude nulls.  `<column> IS NOT NULL and <column> NOT IN (7,8,9)` is the equivalent of `<column> NOT IN (7,8,9)`

Comment: ...and nevermind, that was a blank space.  I'll leave the explanation about NULLs up there anyway.

Comment: And to expand on the answer, if what is ultimately wanted is to find columns where the value is composed of the same, repeated character, then use `WHERE {column} NOT LIKE '%[^' + LEFT({column}, 1) + ']%'`.